# PostgreSQL - data replication stopped

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Data replication has stopped from one of my three nodes. The replication slot on the errant node has disappeared. Does anyone have insight as to what happened or how to fix it?

DETAILS:
Nodes SS1, SS2, and SS3 have publications to which SSK subscribes. Replication from SS2 is now failing. Using PostgreSQL 10.1.

SSK psql log:

```
2019-02-07 10:21:13.953 CST [26274] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "SS2" has started
2019-02-07 10:21:14.309 CST [26274] ERROR:  could not start WAL streaming: ERROR:  replication slot "SS2" does not exist
2019-02-07 10:21:14.311 CST [1641] LOG:  worker process: logical replication worker for subscription 17237 (PID 26274) exited with exit code 1
```

SS2 replication slots table:

```
 slot_name | plugin | slot_type | datoid | database | temporary | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn | confirmed_flush_lsn
-----------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------
(0 rows)
```

For comparison, SS1 replication slots table:

```
 slot_name |  plugin  | slot_type | datoid | database | temporary | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn | confirmed_flush_lsn
-----------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------
 SS1 | pgoutput | logical   |  33280 | DBAdd | f         | t      |       2113 |      |     56655301 | 3/114FB460  | 3/114FB498
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replication slot don't just disappear.

Somebody or something must have deleted it.

Perhaps the PostgreSQL database log of the primary server has valuable information.

Did you promote a standby recently? Since replication slots are not replicated, that would make them disappear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by promoting a standby, but I don't think so. We did have network connectivity issues at the primary server's location. Reviewing the logs on the primary server says:

Comment: 2019-02-03 06:59:36.482 CST [6684] MVA@DBname LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2019-02-03 13:09:55.686 CST [13988] postgres@DBname LOG:  terminating walsender process due to replication timeout
2019-02-03 13:09:55.690 CST [14011] postgres@DBname LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2019-02-03 13:09:55.691 CST [14011] postgres@DBname FATAL:  connection to client lost
2019-02-03 14:09:03.613 CST [15387] postgres@DBname ERROR:  replication slot "site20378" does not exist

Comment: "Promotion" is a term from (physical) streaming replication, so if you don't use that, it is irrelevant. The fact remains that either a human or some external piece of software must have dropped the replication slot, since PostgreSQL doesn't do that by itself.

Comment: I'm the only one with access to the primary server and I didn't drop the rep slot. We're using logical streaming replication if that makes a difference. Still puzzled and still not replicating data... but thank you very much for the information :)